# Logback - Need to send a single email instead of multiple

Tags: java, logback

I am using logback version 1.2.3. I configured an `SMTPAppender` in my logback xml config file like so:

```
<appender name="email" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>warn</level>
    </filter>
    <smtpHost>smtp.mydomain.org</smtpHost>
    <to>code4kix@mydomain.org</to>
    <from>do-not-reply@mydomain.org</from>
    <subject>${HOSTNAME} | %-5level: %logger{20}</subject>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{5}:%L - %msg%n</pattern>
    </layout>
    <asynchronousSending>false</asynchronousSending>
</appender>
```

If I have a Java class like below, it sends me two separate emails. I need them to be in one email. How?

```
logger.error("statement 1");
logger.error("statement 2");
```

Note that adding the content below to the logback config doesn't help. What am I missing?

```
<STARTTLS>true</STARTTLS>
<cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTracker">
    <bufferSize>10</bufferSize>
</cyclicBufferTracker>
<asynchronousSending>false</asynchronousSending>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update the answer. I realized rather quickly it's not as straight forward from logback's perspective. How is it going to know when to trigger the email? What if there's another `logger.error("statement 3");` after these, and then the email is supposed to go out:

```
logger.error("statement 1");
logger.error("statement 2");
```

We would need to explicitly tell logback when to trigger the email. Read more [here](https://logback.qos.ch/recipes/emailPerTransaction.html) about markers.

So you need something like a logger statement at the end to mark when the email triggers:

```
logger.info(SMTP_TRIGGER, "statement last");
```

And also, you would need to update your logback config to something like so:

```
<appender name="SMTP" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>warn</level>
    </filter>
    <smtpHost>smtp.mydomain.org</smtpHost>
    <to>code4kix@mydomain.org</to>
    <from>do-not-reply@mydomain.org</from>
    <subject>${HOSTNAME} | %-5level: %logger{20}</subject>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{5}:%L - %msg%n</pattern>
    </layout>
    <asynchronousSending>false</asynchronousSending>

    <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator">
      <expression>
        marker != null  && marker.contains("SMTP_TRIGGER")
      </expression>
    </evaluator>
 </appender>
```